# initialize file in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't seem to figure out this issue:

`uninitialized constant Five9Controller::Five9Providers`

My files look like this:

## Contact Provider

```
lib/five9_providers/contact_provider.rb

class Five9Providers::ContactProvider < Five9Providers::BaseProvider

  def add_record_to_list(record)
    ....
  end
end
```

## Base Provider

```
lib/five9_providers/base_provider.rb

class Five9Providers::BaseProvider

  def initialize()
    ....
  end

  def other_method()
    ....
  end
end
```

## Controller

```
controllers/five9_controller.rb

class Five9Controller < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def import
    contact_provider = Five9Providers::ContactProvider.new()
    ....
  end
end
```

All of those files combined throw an error:

`uninitialized constant Five9Controller::Five9Providers`

within my controller on the `contact_provider =` line.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you requiring the ```lib/five9_providers/contact_provider.rb``` file? Is it in your autoload path?

Comment: No, I'm not - And I assume that's the issue. Would you mind proposing a solution as to how to require all files in the /lib directory? Where is the best place to put that require? application.rb?

Comment: Adding this to my application.rb file solved the issue - Out of curiosity, is this the best place/way to do this? Thanks. 
   `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)`

Comment: Yes, that's a good way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by adding

`config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)`

to my autoload path.